# Conditions in J2 templates (Ansible)

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I use this syntax in my Jinja template to print the string "foobar" if the content of the custom variables cannot be parsed, and this works well:

```
{{ hostvars[h]['myvar'][0]['myothervar'] | default('foobar') }}
```

Now, I'd like to print the content of the above custom variables if Ansible cannot reach the target machine to fetch the number of CPUs, but this syntax does not work:

```
{{ hostvars[h]['ansible_processor_vcpus'] | hostvars[h]['myvar'][0]['myothervar'] }}
```

It throws instead an error:

```
AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token
'end of print statement', got '['.
```

What would the correct syntax be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `|` operator is not "alternation" (`this | that` does not mean `this OR that`). It's more like a shell pipeline -- it passes the output of the expression on the left to the filter on the right.

Your second expression is not a filter.

You could use the `default` filter, just like in your first example:

```
{{
  hostvars[h]['ansible_processor_vcpus'] |
  default(hostvars[h]['myvar'][0]['myothervar'])
}}
```